# How would sensible waste disposal be accomplished for terrestrial creatures in a primitive society?

Tags: earth-like, fauna, cities, ecology, waste

Necessary context: Various real animals like birds, foxes and snakes plus fictitious ones like qilins/kirins, gryphons and gloomstalkers (raven-like birds with some minor serpent features) possessing human intelligence populate New Zealand and embody Maori culture. Marine creatures such as dolphins are present too, but those aren't the focus here. The planet is earth-like and the flora are identical to those found on the islands today.

These beings reside in scattered villages of various sizes in the range of environments New Zealand possesses. Landbound creatures who cannot fly usually reside in ground level huts, while their winged counterparts most often reside in arboreal dwellings. The former can and do choose to live in elevated dwellings however.

As they are aware that their bodily wastes return nutrients to the soil, they typically venture a short-but-sufficient distance from their village to do their business. This helps keep the surrounding land fertile, as well as avoiding contaminating the village grounds and spreading disease.

This isn't an issue for small villages but becomes a problem in larger settlements, especially those with establishments such as restaurants, lodges, indoor markets, etc. where many individuals are packed into one space. Individuals having to travel beyond village boundaries to answer nature's call is a time-consuming hassle and causes traffic issues.

This culture has access to a handful of natural resources, namely wood, stone, iron, and glass, for construction. Some individuals have the ability to manipulate a certain element, like water, earth, or fire, among others. As an extension of this, they are able to enchant special crystals with their magic to autonomously perform a task.

Taking all this into account, how would large villages with high concentrations of different kinds of individuals tackle this issue? I'm looking for suggestions regarding universal restrooms and a way to transport waste to the outlying lands where it belongs. Solutions that minimize environmental impact and/or are both functional and aesthetically pleasing are preferred.

Comment: why not look at how real historical settlements handled it, because there are many different ways. No reason to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Hint: research [Terra Preta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_preta), similar to Night Soil, only much more so.  Was implemented by stone-age tribes in the Amazon (and similar elsewhere).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, well... it's hard to explain. From a certain point of view it's a normal use-of-technology question, but it's made unrealistically complex by the (probably politically motivated) desire for (of all things) a universal (in this case, *cross-species*) restroom along with transport mechanisms without explaining the size of the cities or the technology level we're working with. There's too many things just a little bit wrong here, so let's fix it.

Answer (score 6):

This will not be a problem. We have plentiful examples of similar historical societies which dealt with accumulations of excrement by treating it as **a valuable resource**; since your animal societies are aware of manure's effect on soil fertility, there's nothing stopping them from doing the same. There are many methods available, and a common one is to let the wastes drain into a pond or a wetland. In there the wastes decompose and load it with nutrients, making an extremely fertile environment for aquatic plants, on which fish can then feed (carp is best because it can surface for air, and so tolerates oxygen-poor waters). Every few years you drain the pond and extract the muck which accumulated on the bottom, which makes excellent fertiliser, and in the meantime you can catch fish to your heart's content. Historically, ponds were so valuable that they were often granted as privileges to monasteries and the like, supplemented by brisk trade in "night soil" which if anything was even more profitable in bigger settlements.

Comment: In feudal Japan, the night soil harvested from wealthy people was sold for a higher price, because it was believed to contain more nutrients due to their richer diet!

Comment: @DangItBilly, thank you. Now that you mentioned it, I can see the feces of some species of anomal people being seen as more valuable for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, which I have seen used until not too long ago, is to do one's business in an underground room where straw has been added. Once in a while stirr the mix or add new steaw and when the room is full, empty it and carry the product to the fields where it can be spread on the soil for fertilising it.